# Symfony2 / Twig - Label class for Expanded choice type

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

How can I change class for expanded choice type **label**? 
Default class is "required", but I need to change it to my own class.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: There is an option called `label_attr` which works almost like `attr`. Try passing your class name to it.

Comment: I need to set class to **expanded** choice. Not just for choice.
expanded choice replace choice to radio buttons, and every radio have label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should render your form field yourself in your twig template like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.expandedField) }}
    <div class="col-md-10">
        {% for child in form.expandedField.children %}
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="expanded" for="{{ child.vars.id }}">
                    {{ form_widget(child) }}
                    {{ child.vars.label }}
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Every form element has a `children` attribute which is used for any child elements. In your case your radio buttons. Iterate over them and generate you label for every element with all those classes you need yourself.